# ng-repeat changing the data depending on content of div

Tags: angularjs

For every element in ng-repeat I need to display an icon with it.That is for each div a different icon should be displayed depending on the content.What is the right way to go about it?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="overview">
    <i class="fa fa-{{}}"></i>
    <div class="overflow-h padding-top" ng-repeat="attributes in places.attributes">
        {{attributes.name}}
    </div>    
</div>
```

For every attribute a different icon should be displayed.

Comment: Please consider sharing your codes and the point where you are stuck.Otherwise its too broad question and may have many answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, I've used FontAwesome icons and added a class based on the value of an object attribute.

```
<div ng-repeat='row in data'>
  <i class='fa fa-{{row.icon}}'></i>
</div>
```

This will generate a div having the icon specified in the `row.icon` attribute. For the mapping between names and icons you can consult the FontAwesome site.